# KeyDown functions not activating

Tags: c#

I've been making a game called dog simulator. Im at the point on where the movement needs to be developed, however, for some reason, the function didn't activate. Visual Studio (the IDE I use) said there were no errors. Some help will be appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dog_simulator
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool right;
        bool left;
        public int left_var = 5;
        public int right_var = 5;

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        public void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Left has been pressed");
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                left = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Left has been pressed");
            }
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                right = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Right has been pressed");
            }
        }

        public void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                left = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Left has been let go of");
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                right = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Right has been let go of");
            }
        }

        public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (right == true)
            {
                player.Left += left_var;

            }
            if (left == true)
            {
                player.Left -= left_var;
            }
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void dog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void player_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the KeyPreview property to True?

Comment: It worked! Well, I have to click out of it and then click it back in, how do I make it so I dont have to do that?

Comment: That's not clear. Please post a new question with only the relevant details. A new question will be seen by more people and perhaps someone could help you better

Comment: Im sorry, its just that I don't want to trash this place with trash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Windows Form to be able to see the key pressed you need to set the

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

in designer or in form code. Otherwise the key presses will be received by the control that has the current focus.

MSDN: [Form.KeyPreview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx)